# Opening files with quickly's PyGTK

Tags: application-development, quickly, pygtk

I have already added the listeners and etc, but I can't get the actual open dialog code to work.  I think it is something to do with the difference between gtk and Gtk but I literally just started python yesterday.
Here is my code as of now:

```
dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open..",
                           None,
                           GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                           (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                            Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
    dialog.set_default_response(Gtk.RESPONSE_OK)
```

When the button is pressed, the console output this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nja/notetaker/notetaker/NotetakerWindow.py", line 61, in on_btn_open_clicked
self.open_file()
File "/home/nja/notetaker/notetaker/NotetakerWindow.py", line 41, in open_file
GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
NameError: global name 'GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN' is not defined
```

Also when `GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN` is substituted for "0" (Which I believe is the `int` that constant points to) it works fine but it flags up the same error on `Gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL` and `Gtk.RESPONSE_OK`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must replace:

- `GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN` with `Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN`
- `Gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL` with `Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL`
- `Gtk.RESPONSE_OK` with `Gtk.ResponseType.OK`

etc.

This is not PyGTK, it's GObject Introspection. You must build names as follows: `Gtk.EnumTypeNameHere.VALUE`

See https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting

Comment: I will vote your answer up as soon as I have the sufficient reputation :)